# What is the best way to compare an incoming database query with your local datasource for creations, deletions, and updates?

Tags: arrays, swift, database, firebase

Obviously this is a common logic puzzle for a programmer that does not want to clear and repopulate their entire local datasource every time a database listener fires with an update.

I am using Swift, and I have an array of objects with a unique ID attribute that is being used as a datasource for a tableview. When my FireStore snapshot listener is called with a new set of objects, what is the cleanest / most efficient way to determine which objects are new, deleted, or need to be updated?

Assuming I am iterating over the new list of objects

`for obj in incomingObjects {`

Right now I am checking if my local datasource contains the incoming object for updates

`if myDatasource.contains(where: {$0.id == obj.id})`

Checking if it doesnt contain the object for creations (is an else in practice)

`if !myDatasource.contains(where: {$0.id == obj.id})`

And I have an array being built of all the incoming objects, so at the end I can delete missing instances.

How do accomplish the same feat? Functional logic is functional logic, your answer could be in pseudocode.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a fair question asking about receiving discreet changes to your database without having to re-load everything. It's unclear to me why it was closed. You may have overlooked it but getting those changes is briefly covered in the Firestore documentation [View Changes Between Snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots). I am upvoting and voting to re-open as there's a great and complete answer that would benefit future readers.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I didn't see that mentioned in the docs, despite how often I frequent them. Unbelievable sometimes how easy Firebase makes things. This will save me a lot of time and complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FireStore snapshot has a `documentChanges` property. In your listener you are going to iterate over all of the changes and map those to index paths. Once you have done that you will need to update your data source with the new data (I'll leave that as an exercise for you) then you need to update the table view as illustrated below.

```
db.collection("cities").whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA")
    .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        var insertions: [IndexPath] = []
        var modifications: [IndexPath] = []
        var deletions: [IndexPath] = []
        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
            if (diff.type == .added) {
                print("New city: \(diff.document.data())")
                insertions.append(.init(row: diff.newIndex, section: 0))
            }
            if (diff.type == .modified) {
                print("Modified city: \(diff.document.data())")
                modifications.append(.init(row: diff.newIndex, section: 0))
            }
            if (diff.type == .removed) {
                print("Removed city: \(diff.document.data())")
                deletions.append(.init(row: diff.oldIndex, section: 0))
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            // TODO: update your data source before you update the UI

            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: insertions, with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications, with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions, with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
}
```